# Redshift count consecutive days based on a condition and break(stop counting) when the condition doesn't

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions

Table

```
Date    Region_1    Region_2
27-Sep  100       97.69
28-Sep  53.84   98.21
29-Sep  88.88   10
30-Sep  8.33    96
01-Oct  25     97.63
02-Oct  20     94.82
03-Oct  25     100
04-Oct  12.5    60.86
05-Oct  10      67.29
06-Oct  42.85   63.85
07-Oct  7.14    66.25
08-Oct  14.28   71.05
09-Oct  16.66   69.48
10-Oct  25      72.64
11-Oct  12.5    0
```

expected output

```
Region_1_Compliant_days      Region_2_compliant_Days
1                                       2
```

I'm trying to count consecutive days for each region only when the percent is greater than 60 %. But I'm not getting the right result.

```
case when region_1 > 60.0 and count(date) over (partition by date desc) then 1 else 0 end
```

But the above is calculating all the instances greater than 60.0 and not just the consecutive days.

explanation:
region1 on 27th is 100. Hence it is counted as it is greater than 60. but on 28th it is 50. Since it doesn't meet the condition I'll stop counting from there. Same goes with region2

Region2 has a lot of days more than 60. But the reason I'm considering only 2 days is: on 27th and 28th the value is greater than 60 but on 29th it is 10., which means the chain breaks there. So I'm only counting first two days.. even though we have more 60 for the rest of the days post 29th.

Please let me know how can this is achieved.

Thanks

Comment: May be I don't get it but how you expect the result as `Region_1_Compliant_days    1` ?

Comment: region1 on 27th is 100. Hence it is counted as it is greater than 60. but on 28th it is 50. Since it doesn't meet the condition I'll stop counting from there. Same goes with region2

Comment: Can you please explain your expected output in greater detail? Region 2 appears to have many more than 2 consecutive days where the value is > 60%. Just trying to make sure I understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: May be consecutive days is not the right title. Let me try to explain. 
Region2 has a lot of days more than 60. But the reason I'm considering only 2 days is: on 27th and 28th the value is greater than 60 but on 29th it is 10., which means the chain breaks there. So I'm only counting first two days.. even though we have more 60 for the rest of the days post 29th.

Comment: @Kalyan Prasad, I don't have redshift but does it support window function ?

Comment: yes, it supports. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Window_functions.html

Comment: @@Kalyan Prasad, did it work ?

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30, not working. I keep getting error for this statement min((region_1 > 60))
error:  function min(boolean) does not exist;

Comment: I just edited my answer .please check again

Comment: Why don't you count the 2nd group of rows over 60 in region_2 (11 rows starting with 30-Sep)? You only want rows over 60 starting at 27-Sep and stop counting as soon as the value gets lower?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you try with below query,

```
select sum(Region_1_Compliant_days) Region_1_Compliant_days
      ,sum(Region_2_Compliant_days) Region_2_Compliant_days
  from
(
select d.*
      ,min(case when region_1 > 60 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by dt rows between unbounded preceding and current row) Region_1_Compliant_days
      ,min(case when region_2 > 60 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by dt rows between unbounded preceding and current row) Region_2_Compliant_days
from table1 d
) t;
```

Using window clause we always look for a window between all previous rows and current row and if we found min as 0 which means there is a value < 60 and then set to 0 for all afterwards

Hope I make sense and it works as expected.

Comment: No need for the `case`: `min(case when region_1 > 60 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by dt rows between unbounded preceding and current row)` returns the same.

Comment: @dnoeth, you are absolutely right and thank you for that. Never realised that.

Comment: Thank you @Sujitmohanty30 and dnoeth

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the dates are consecutive, you don't need window functions:

```
select datediff(day,
                min(date),
                min(case when region_1 <= 0.6 then date end)
               ) as region_1,
       datediff(day,
                min(date),
                min(case when region_2 <= 0.6 then date end)
               ) as region_2
from t;
```

This simply returns the number of days between the first date in the data and the minimum date that does not meet your condition.  To me, this seems like the simplest way to answer the question.

If there are no days less than 0.6, then the logic needs a slight tweak:

```
select datediff(day,
                min(date),
                coalesce(min(case when region_1 <= 0.6 then date end), max(date) + interval '1 day')
               ) as region_1,
       datediff(day,
                min(date),
                coalesce(min(case when region_2 <= 0.6 then date end), max(date) + interval '1 day')
               ) as region_2
from t;
```